# Jquery autocomplete combobox plugin event when value delete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

For check selected value I use this:

```
$( "#combobox1" ).combobox( {
            select: function (event, ui) {
                var value=$( "#combobox1 option:selected" ).text();
               ...
        });
```

How can I check if value from input was deleted(e.g is empty)?

Comment: what is your data source, javascript array?

Comment: no, select :`<select id="combobox1" style="display: none;">
<option value="Claudine HATEBUR DE CALDERóN">Claudine HATEBUR DE CALDERóN</option>
<option value="Lilly R. EHRET">Lilly R. EHRET</option>
<option value="Tamara ROTH">Tamara ROTH</option>
</select>`

Comment: best thing is that you paste all your code in the question so I can understand it better

Answer (score 0):

here, I have build you full example and commented it in details,, hope that you can find it helpfull

```js
function allmaped(){
  // add all options from select to array
  var arr = [];
  $('#combobox1').find('option').each(function(e){ arr.push( $(this).val() )});
  // define autocomplete
  $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({ source:arr });
}

// run this on pageload
allmaped();
// if click on remove button OR any other event removes select options => rebuild it!
$('#remove').on( 'click', function(){ 
  $('#combobox1').find('option').eq(0).remove(); 
  $( '#tags' ).autocomplete( "destroy" );
  // run autocomplete function again
  allmaped();  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>

<div><button id="remove">REMOVE OPTION 1</button></div>

<select id="combobox1" style="display: none;">
 <option value="Claudine HATEBUR DE CALDERóN">Claudine HATEBUR DE CALDERóN</option>
 <option value="Lilly R. EHRET">Lilly R. EHRET</option>
 <option value="Tamara ROTH">Tamara ROTH</option>
 <option value="Tamara BOTH">Tamara BOTH</option>
 <option value="Tamara GOTH">Tamara GOTH</option>
</select>
```